# Samba share suddenly stopped showing on Windows

Tags: linux, windows, samba, network-share

I have 20 computers in my office network and all the computers run windows10 except one which is running Ubuntu. I have setup a samba share on that machine so that others can access the share drive which I have mapped as a network drive. This worked fine for months and today for some reason the drive shows the capacity on Windows "This PC" , but when opened it says, It is empty.
I tried booting one of those PCs with a Linux USB and it successfully shows the contents and no errors. Also I can access the network drive on android file manager.

I can confirm now that the samba share cannot be accessed on Windows, which worked fine earlier.

How can I fix this issue and show the samba content on Windows10?